# Is a linear isometric surjection a homeomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear map between two Banach spaces. If $T$ is isometric and surjective, is $T$ a homeomorphism?

attempt: I think the answer is yes, it is a homeomorphism. To prove it, here is a sketch:

Since $T$ is a linear isometry, $T$ is continuous.
For $T^{-1}$, note that it is linear and bounded due to the Bounded Inverse Theorem. Thus, $T^{-1}$ is continuous.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't apply the bounded inverse theorem until you know that $T$ is bijective! You're only given that it's surjective.

Comment: $T$ is assumed to be isometric and surjective. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, but the entire point of the exercise is to explain why!

Comment: Oh, I posed it as a question because I wasn't sure that it's going to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were given this as an exercise. Anyway, the answer is yes but you need to say something to get that $T$ is bijective.

Comment: To clarify: 1) I think that it is a homeomorphism. 2) Here is a proof attempt. Is it correct?

Comment: 1) Yes, it's a homeomorphism. 2) As I have said twice already, you haven't explained why $T$ is bijective, and without that you can't apply the bounded inverse theorem.

Comment: You get one-to-one from the isometry condition while surjectivity is given.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but it's the only step of the proof before applying the bounded inverse theorem so you should write it explicitly.

Comment: If $Tx=Ty$, then $0=||Tx-Ty||=||T(x-y)||=||x-y||$. Hence, $x=y$. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes! Now you've got a proof. Note furthermore that because $T$ is an isometry, so is its inverse, so you actually don't even need to apply the bounded inverse theorem.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the input. I thought that was clear.

Comment: Well, everything is clear to someone, I suppose. But it's worth saying explicitly, in my opinion. If I were grading this as a homework problem I'd take points off for not saying it explicitly.

Comment: Fair enough. It is not a homework though. I am trying to get some intuition with the objects, hence the original question. You are right, the bounded inverse theorem is not needed if one observes that $T^{-1}$ is also an isometry. So the assumption that the domain and codomain can be relaxed to normed spaces I think.

Comment: Yes, that seems right to me.